# On the definition of Gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, proof-explanation, almost-everywhere

I´m having a hard time understanding the proof of theorem $14.3$ of the lecture notes of Gordan Zitkovic about multivariate Guassian vectors:

https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/brownian_motion.pdf

In particular the implication $1\to 3$ :

Suppose we have a Gaussian Vector $X=(X_1,...,X_n)^T$ such that it´s characteristic function is $$\phi_x(t)=e^{it^T\mu - \frac{t^T\Sigma t}{2}}$$ 
where $\mu \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{M_{nxn}(\mathbb R)}$ is a symmetric nonnegative definite matrix with $rank(\Sigma) = d \in \{1,...,n\}$

We wish to prove that there exists a matrix $A\in \mathbb {M_{nxd}(\mathbb {R})}$ such that:

1) $rank(A) = d$

2) there exists a random vector $Y = (Y_1,...,Yd)^T$ defined in the same probability space as $X$ which consists of independent unit normals such that $$X = AY + \mu$$

Here is the proof (I have adapted some parts):

> By replacing $X$ by $X − µ$, where $µ = E[X]$, we can assume,
>   without loss of generality, that $E[X] = 0$. By nonnegative definitiness and  symmetry we have that:$$ Q^T\Sigma Q = diag(\lambda_1,...\lambda_d,0,...0)$$ where $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_d > 0$ and $Q$ is a matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,....,e_n\}$ consisting of the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$.
>   Let $T$ be the matrix whose columns are the first $d$ eigenvectors $\{e_1,...,e_d\}$. We have that:
>   $$1) T^T \Sigma T = diag(\lambda_1,..., \lambda_d)$$
>   $$2) T^T T = I_{\mathbb R^{dxd}} \in M_{dxd}(\mathbb R) $$ (the identity matrix with respect to the canonical basis)
>   $$3) T T^T \in M_{nxn}(\mathbb R)$$ such that $T T^Te_{i}=e_i$ for all $1\le i \le d$ and $T T^Te_{i}=(0,...,0)$ for all $d+1\le i \le n$.
>    Let $Y = diag((\lambda_1)^{-1/2},...,(\lambda_d)^{-1/2}) T^T X$. If we compute the characteristic function of $Y$ we have that: 
>   $$ \phi_Y(t)=\phi_X(T diag((\lambda_1)^{-1/2},...,(\lambda_d)^{-1/2})t) = e^{-\frac{t^2_1+...+t^2_d}{2}}$$ which is the same of a characteristic function of $d$ independent unit normals. So $Y$ consist of $d$ independent unit normals.
>   Now let $A=T diag((\lambda_1)^{1/2},...,(\lambda_d)^{1/2})$. Observe that $rank(A)=d$ and $AY=TT^TX$

**It remains to show that $TT^T X=X$ almost surely** :

> On one hand we clearly have $|| TT^Tx|| \le ||x||$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$. On the other the random vectors $TT^TX, X$ have the same characteristic function, and are therefore equally distributed. Consequently $TT^TX=X$ almost surely.

I am having trouble with the last part: I understand that $TT^TX$ and $X$ have the same characteristic function. I just don´t see why :

1) $|| TT^Tx|| \le ||x||$ for all $x$ and

2) **this implies that $TT^TX=X$ almost surely.**

I´ve been stuck with this problem, and I just don´t see how to prove it.

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this source is reliable. If $S=-I$ then $\|Sx\| \leq \|x\|$. If $X$ has a symmetric distribution then $SX$ and $X$ have the same distribution. But we cannot conclude that $X=-X$ almost surely. So 1) implies 2) is false.

Comment: If $S$ is any linear transformation then this is false as you have pointed out, but in this case $S= TT^T$ so this linear transformation maps the vectors $\{e_1,...,e_d\}$ to $\{e_1,...,e_d\}$ (its like an identity matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$TT^{T}$ is an orthogonal projection because $\{e_{i}\}$ are orthonormal basis. Hence the first claim.

The event that $TT^{T}X=X$ is the same as the event that $X\in image(TT^{t})$ which is the image of the projection. Since $TT^{T}X$ is equally distributed with $X$ this has the same probability as the event that $TT^{T}X\in image(TT^{t})$, which is $1$.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! I just have one last question: I can see that the event $\{\omega \in \Omega : TT^TX=X\} \subset \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in image(TT^T) \}$ but why is the other inclusion also true? if $X(\omega) \in image(TT^T)$ then there exist $x´$ such that $X(\omega)= TT^Tx´$ I just don´t see why $X(\omega)=x´$?

Comment: @user128422: write $S=TT^{T}$ then $S^{2} =S$ because this is a projection. So if $X(\omega)=Sx$ then $SX(\omega)=SSx=S^{2}x=Sx=X(\omega)$